# EF Core 7 Json column type migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-7.0

I have an entity model with EF Core 7 with Json Column type. After a while I added new fields to the Json column. Does EF has any utility for Json column migrations?
Currently after I add a new field to the Json column it produces following exceptions when I get list of existing entities:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
         at lambda_method179(Closure , QueryContext , Object[] , JsonElement )
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.IncludeJsonEntityCollection[TIncludingEntity,TIncludedCollectionElement](QueryContext queryContext, Nullable`1 jsonElement, Object[] keyPropertyValues, TIncludingEntity entity, Func`4 innerShaper, Action`2 fixup)
         at lambda_method178(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
      System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
         at lambda_method179(Closure , QueryContext , Object[] , JsonElement )
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.IncludeJsonEntityCollection[TIncludingEntity,TIncludedCollectionElement](QueryContext queryContext, Nullable`1 jsonElement, Object[] keyPropertyValues, TIncludingEntity entity, Func`4 innerShaper, Action`2 fixup)
         at lambda_method178(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

This is the code example for my entities:

```
public class ReportTemplate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<ReportParam> ReportParams { get; set; } = new();
}
public class ReportParam
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Prompt { get; set; }
    public bool AllowBlank { get; set; } = false;
    public bool Nullable { get; set; } = false;
}
builder.OwnsMany(s => s.ReportParams, ob => ob.ToJson());
```

I want to change the ReportParam to:

```
public class ReportParam
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Prompt { get; set; }
    public bool AllowBlank { get; set; } = false;
    public bool Nullable { get; set; } = false;
    public bool AllowMultipleValues { get; set; } = false;
    public bool Hidden { get; set; } = false;

}
```

Comment: You might have bumped against https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30028

Comment: Or rather: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29219

Answer (score 0):

Until the issues are fixed (and I don't know if those issues will address the non-nullable primitives like bool or int), you can manually add a SQL statement in migration Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) method, something like:

migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE ReportTemplate SET ReportParams = REPLACE(ReportParams, '}', '"AllowMultipleValues":false,"Hidden":false}')");

This will add the missing values to Json string in the table.

Comment: Instead of fiddling around with string functions, you should probably use the existing T-SQL JSON functions like JSON_MODIFY. For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42564593/331281